# could not find gem spree-stock-manager, source does not contain any versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I've been searching for a solution to this problem but been unable to find it.

I'm trying to add spree-stock-manager to my vanilla spree test store (1.2.0).

When I run 'bundle install' i get

```
Could not find gem 'spree-stock-manager (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/olivierbuffon/spree-stock-manager.git (at master). Source does not contain any versions of 'spree-stock-manager (>= 0) ruby'
```

I tried downloading and installing it as a local gem into vendor/gems and also added a specific version to my Gemfile (suggestion from Stackoverflow). Same result only said (= 1.1.0) instead of (>= 0).

I looked into the .gemspec for spree_stock_manager and it said

```
 s.add_dependency 'spree_core', '~> 1.1.0'
```

so that should include spree_core 1.2.0, right?

Other info:
Mac OSX, rvm, rails 3.2.9

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.add_dependency 'spree_core', '~> 1.1.0'
```

This indicates that it requires any version of spree_core from 1.1.0 up to, but NOT including 1.2.0.

I would be weary of using this gem for a couple reasons. First, there are no tests associated with it, which tells me the author doesn't care enough about the code to take the time to document the expected behavior. It also won't be easy for others to contribute bug fixes or enhancements without tests. Second, the gem isn't registered at rubygems.org. While not required, this is the standard gem repo and tells me that the author had no intention of actually releasing it publicly.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer. I'll search for something else then.